# Static ip for Virtualbox using bridge connection

Tags: virtualbox, bridge

I need to use the remoteapp on Ubuntu 14.04 using virtualbox running Win7. But the real problem is I can only access the remoteapp when connected to a wlan or eth using bridge network. Otherwise it won't let me connect. Is there any solution to have virtual wlan or eth which is always active and give a static ip address no matter what I connect to. Here what I want...

Vbox Net(192.168.1.2) ----> Bridge ----> Virtual_eth2 (192.168.1.3) Always active --> Bridge (To access Internet)---> eth0(192.168.30.2) or wlan0(192.168.25.5)

Comment: So you want to prevent NATting because port forwarding would be too much of a hassle?

Comment: Exactly. Just want to access the remoteapp even when not connected to any ethernet or wifi.